# Can I have multiple loaders running simultaneously?

Tags: android

Is it possible to have two separate loader callbacks for different loaders running at the same time? I couldn't find the answer online.
I'm asking because that's what I'm trying to do, but the second loader isn't instantiating a new CursorLoader in onCreateLoader when I try...

the program gets stuck at bla = new CursorLoader(...) and doesn't print the Log after that line.

Comment: Why don't you try ajax?

Comment: Isn't that for web development? Not sure if I can use it for android, I'm trying to use the native loader

Comment: It should be possible. Can you post relevant code for context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, can have multiple loaders as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

> The LoaderManager manages one or more Loader instances within an
>   Activity or Fragment. There is only one LoaderManager per activity or
>   fragment.

As to why you are having issues it is hard to say without seeing any code for context.